# TabBar indicator custom shape

Tags: flutter, tabbar

I tried to create `TabBar` indicator according to this shape.

[image]

My current code looks like this

```dart
TabBar(
  isScrollable: true,
  controller: _tabController,
  tabs: _tabList,
  labelColor: Colors.black,
  labelStyle: _generalTitleStyle,
  // indicatorColor: Colors.black,
  indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
  indicatorWeight: 4.0,
  indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
  indicator: ShapeDecoration(
    shape: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 8.0),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.elliptical(50, 360),
        topRight: Radius.elliptical(50, 360),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Which resulting it to be like this

[image]

But when I changed the `borderRadius` bits to

```dart
borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
  bottomLeft: Radius.elliptical(50, 360),
  bottomRight: Radius.elliptical(50, 360),
),
```

It's actually work, but not in the form that I wanted

[image]

How do I actually make it so it will shape like the image on top?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want show your line like https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSjgR.png

Comment: @AmitPrajapati no, like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMlpk.png

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom shape for indicator.

Here is the code:

```
class MyShape extends ShapeBorder {
  int shapeDistance = 5;
  @override
  // TODO: implement dimensions
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => null;

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    // TODO: implement getInnerPath
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    // TODO: implement getOuterPath
    return null;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    final paint = Paint();
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(rect.bottomLeft.dx + shapeDistance, rect.bottomLeft.dy);
    path.lineTo(rect.bottomLeft.dx, rect.bottomLeft.dy + shapeDistance);
    path.lineTo(rect.bottomRight.dx, rect.bottomRight.dy + shapeDistance);
    path.lineTo(rect.bottomRight.dx - shapeDistance, rect.bottomRight.dy);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) {
    // TODO: implement scale
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then set it in

```
ShapeDecoration(
   shape: MyShape()
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. However, when I apply the code `indicator: ShapeDecoration(shape: MyShape(),),`, the indicator bar instantly disappeared. Any idea why this happen?